# I have an issue with secret question input regular expressions In Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Any suggestions on how to include double quotes ("") in this expression?

```
InputField("tSecAnswer1", /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z\d])(\w|[\s\.\@\-\?\,\&\/\_\#\+\(\)\"'"]){3,50}$/);
```

Comment: Not intending to sound rude, but I would suggest having a serious read through some regular expression tutorials.  What you have already has problems and I'm not sure where I would start explaining them.

Comment: you are not rude. These files were not written by me. And the usual approaches I am taking have not worked so that is why I am asking. I take no offense at all.

Comment: You only need to escape `/`, `]`, `\⁠`, and in some cases the `-` in character sets: `[\s.@\-?,&\/_#+()"']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I fixed the issue with including a single and double quote in my regular expression.

```
InputField("tSecAnswer2", /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z\d])(\w|[\s\.\@\-\?\,\&\/\_\#\+\(\)\"'"\'"']){3,50}$/);
```

Comment: `^(?=.*[a-zA-Z\d])[\w\s.@?,&/_#+()"'-]{3,50}$` - The `\w` belongs inside the character class, and you don't need the parentheses around it.  And you should not need to jump through all those hoops to match an apostrophe or a quotation mark.  In a regex literal they have no special meaning.

Comment: Hey I am just going with what works. And the I am having no issues on the form. Again I did not write this file I am just fixing the errors.